# React sub component changes one property in a root state object - will all sub components render or not?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management, react-context

Note, I changed the description of my question a bit. The state is an object with many properties, not an array. Even though if it were an array, the question would still hold and be similar...

I'm developing a react web application. The root component has a state variable called `user`. `user` has many properties and each sub component only uses a subset of them. I'm thinking of using the react context API plus `Memo` to let all the sub components have access to `user`. I've read that using Memo will cause only the changed sub components to render and not all of them. But I'm unsure if I'm implementing all of this correctly and perhaps all the subcomponents WILL render?

A scenario that will happen is that one of the sub components makes a change to one of the properties in `user` and calls `set_user(newUserWithOnePropertyUpdated)` in the root component. So will all sub components render or only the ones that need to?

Comment: Add console.log()s to your components and find out yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case the sub-components *will* re-render, even when using React.memo().

### re-render

A component re-renders, if a passed property is not **referentially equal** to the one in the previous render.

So, if you pass your `user`-object to the sub-components props, and the `user`-object is not the same one that it was before, all the sub-components re-render, even if you use React.memo().

In React you usually will update a state by replacing the whole object, so the `user`-object will always be a new one, and all sub-components using the `user`-object will re-render (even with React.memo()).

To **avoid re-render** with React.memo, you can:

- Only pass primitive values to the props (e.g. strings or numbers).
- Split your `users`-object into smaller object, which only change if the sub-component should also change, and pass these smaller objects to the sub-components props (the `user`-object may still hold references to these smaller objects).
- use the second parameter of [React.memo( component, isEqual )](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo), to manually define what should be considered "a change".

### optimize or not

However, without knowing your exact use case, **it might not be necessary** to optimize with React.memo(), as React is efficient in "re-rendering": it might re-render the component structure (which is fast), but not the visible DOM tree (which is slow).

React.memo() usually becomes important only if very many components have to be re-rendered, or very often (renders per time).

Comment: Thanks so much for an awesome answer :)